# Mulesoft Salesforce Connector Error - (InvalidBatch : Failed to parse CSV. Not expecting more text after end quote)

Tags: csv, salesforce, dataweave, mulesoft, bulk-load

I am trying to process a CSV file (separator = comma) that has columns with values containing comma, back-slash, forward-slash, double quotes.

Sample CSV:

```
Id,Name,RecordTypeId,Start_Date__c,Collab_Data
8701928,John Revor,2022-09-01,"[{""respId"":""a2s2i000000HoE0AAK"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoE2AAK"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoE4AAK"",""details"":""English""},{""respId"":""30928HoECAA0"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoEEAA0"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoEGAA0"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoEIAA0"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoE6AAK"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoE8AAK"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoEKAA0"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoELAA0"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoETAA0"",""details"":""Test Data""},{""respId"":""30928HoEOAA0"",""details"":""test communication""},{""respId"":""30928HoEVAA0"",""details"":""Excellent""},{""respId"":""30928HoEWAA0"",""details"":""Test Data 123""},{""respId"":""30928HoEXAA0"",""details"":""Test Data 435""},{""respId"":""30928HoEaAAK"",""details"":""[{\""respId\"":\""30928HoEbAAK\"",\""details\"":\""180\""},{\""respId\"":\""30928HoEcAAK\"",\""details\"":\""479\""},{\""respId\"":\""30928HoEZAA0\"",\""details\"":10.393117283950618}]""}]
```

I first configured the File Read connector for output-mime type as follows:
[image: File Read Connector]

Then when setting for transformation to convert to java for further mapping logics, used the following dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
input payload application/csv escape='"', quote='"'
output application/java
---
payload
```

Then finally before upserting to Salesforce using the Mulesoft Salesforce connector (Create job bulk api v 2), used the following dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator=",",quoteValues=true,escape=""
---
payload //Here there is some simple logic set which has not been posted here
```

But Salesforce is throwing the following error:

> "InvalidBatch : Failed to parse CSV. Not expecting more text after end
> quote"

What could be causing the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made the escape character of your output csv as a blank character. Therefore it is not escaping the double quotes correctly that is included within the values.

To use double quote as the escape character change the output derivative to

```
output application/csv separator=",",quoteValues=true,escape='"'
```

in your final Dataweave